# Proof explanation on a group of order $595$ having a normal Sylow $17$-subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, sylow-theory

Prove that a group of order 595 has a normal Sylow 17-subgroup.

The proof is as follows:

> By Sylow, $n_{17} = 1$ or $35$. Assume $n_{17} = 35$. Then the union of the Sylow
>   $17$-subgroups has $561$ elements. By Sylow, $n_5 = 1$. Thus, we may form a
>   cyclic subgroup of order $85$ (from a previous theorem) But then there are $64$ elements of order $85$. This gives too many elements.

My question is:  Where does this $64$ come from?

Comment: $ \varphi(85) = 64 $.

Comment: What's $\phi(85)$ represent?

Comment: See Dietrich Burde's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from Euler's totient function, i.e., 
$$
 \phi(85)=64.
$$
Indeed, a cyclic group $C_n$ of order $n$ has exactly $\phi(n)$ generators, i.e., elements of order $n$.

Comment: Just a follow up question, how does this show that there's too many elements?  It just seems to show that there's $64$ ways to represent that group of order $85$.

Comment: See the answers in the duplicate, i.e., count the elements.

Comment: I can't quite see how the answers in the duplicate question answer the question I just asked.

Comment: Give it a try. If you do the calculations from the duplicate, you will immediately see what to do with $35(17-1)$ and $64$.

Comment: I'm still don't understand.  There's $64$ different elements that can be used to represent that specific subgroup of order $85$.  How does the fact that there are $64$ different generators for that subgroup imply that there are too many elements?  and what does $35(17-1) + 64$ represent?

Comment: @OliverG We've proven that there are at least $64$ elements of order $85$ and at least $560$ elements of order $17$ and one from order $1$ But as every order is unique to an element we have that there are at least $560+1+64=625$ elements in $G$. But $G$ is a group of order $595$, which is the number of elements in $G$. Obviously $625>595$